# Why can't I set content to my returned object (Java)?

Tags: java, variables, methods

I'm trying to call a drawable spectrum from my controller, then set the following data to it. I keep getting an error that the left side must be a variable. The call is getting a `specPanel(JPanel)` which has a `DrawableSpectrum` assigned to it. `SpecPanel` has a method called get Spectrum which returns this spectrum. In both of these call I put a `System.out.println` if they are not null, and they never are.

Am I missing something here?

```
con.getSpecPanel().getSpectrum() = (DrawableSpectrum)interpreter.getShapes().get(0);
```

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot assign a value to an object _instance_. You can to a reference, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Spectrum`'s setter instead, assuming you have one. If you don't you should implement it and then you can set the data like this:

```
con.getSpecPanel().setSpectrum((DrawableSpectrum)interpreter.getShapes().get(0));
```

Assignations can be made on fields and variables, that's what the setter does under the hood.

Comment: dammit, wow. I can't believe I didn't think of that. Good stuff